# Two javascript files overwriting each other (conflicts)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem I am encountering is that I have included two javascript files inside index.html, ExhaustTemperature.js and CylinderPressure.js.

The idea is when I click on list_row1 then table1 from ExhaustTemperature.js will show up, and when I click on list_row2 then table2 from CylinderPressure.js will show up.

I believe that the two javascript files are overwriting each other because they have similar method names, is it possible to prevent this overwriting?

My index.html file.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ExhaustTemperature.js"></script> // table1
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/CylinderPressure.js"></script> // table2

        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#' id='list_row1'>Exhaust Temperature</a></li>
            <li class="list-group-item"><a href='#' id='list_row2'>Cylinder Pressure</a></li>
        </ul>

    <div id = "table1">table1</div>
    <div id = "table2">table2</div>
<script>    
           // hide the tables by default when page loads
            $('#table1').hide();
            $('#table2').hide();

            $('#list_row1').on('click',function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); // halt the anchor tag's default behaviour
                $('#table2').hide();
                $('#table1').show();
            });

            $('#list_row2').on('click',function(event){
                event.preventDefault(); // halt the anchor tag's default behaviour
                $('#table1').hide();
                $('#table2').show();
            });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
*(the below content was posted by OP as an answer -Alexander Zhak)*
Here is the content of **ExhaustTemperature.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ExhaustTemperature.js"></script>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

    var dps = []; // dataPoints

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("table1",{
        title :{
            text: "Live Random Data"
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: dps 
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 20;
    var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function (count) {
        count = count || 1;
        // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
            xVal++;
        };
        if (dps.length > dataLength)
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }

        chart.render();     

    };

    // generates first set of dataPoints
    updateChart(dataLength); 

    // update chart after specified time. 
    setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

}
</script>
```

Here is the content of **CylinderPressure.js.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/CylinderPressure.js"></script>
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

    var dps = []; // dataPoints

    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("table2",{
        title :{
            text: "Live Random Data"
        },          
        data: [{
            type: "line",
            dataPoints: dps 
        }]
    });

    var xVal = 0;
    var yVal = 100; 
    var updateInterval = 20;
    var dataLength = 500; // number of dataPoints visible at any point

    var updateChart = function (count) {
        count = count || 1;
        // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.

        for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {   
            yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));
            dps.push({
                x: xVal,
                y: yVal
            });
            xVal++;
        };
        if (dps.length > dataLength)
        {
            dps.shift();                
        }

        chart.render();     

    };

    // generates first set of dataPoints
    updateChart(dataLength); 

    // update chart after specified time. 
    setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 

}
</script>
```

Comment: Show us the contents of the included scripts. With the code you've provided is not possible to tell what's going on. Also: what doe you mean by overriding?

Comment: Whithout seeing your HTML and Javascript code, make the names of functions different, like: 'et_function_One()' and 'cp_function_One()'. A small advantage is you can better identify the places of errors.

Comment: I have put the content of both scripts. @Anzeo

Answer (score 1):

They are not "overwriting each other", they are replacing the methods that have the excact same names..

To avoid this issue, consider creating the two scripts as objects.

```
//construct the object by running this "constructor" method
function myObjectName() {
    //stuff like default values for this script
    this.myAttribute = "default value";
}

myObjectName.prototype.myFunction1 = function(parameter, list){
    //what to do, when the function is called.
    //access the variables of this object like this:
    alert( this.myAttribute );
}
```

Initialise and build the object, (remember to store a global reference, for easy access):

```
var myObject = new myObjectName();
```

now call the functions as you normally would, but remember the reference to the object:

```
myObject.myFunction1("value", "List");
```